# Printing two lists on one line

Tags: python

I have two lists.

```
SpeedList = ["25","30"]
NameList = ["John Smith","Tom Smith"]
```

..And I want to print each element of each list together on one line. So it will say something along the lines of `John Smith was driving at 25 mph` And `Tom Smith was driving at 30 mph` on a second line.

I've tried:

```
print (NameList)," Was driving at ",(SpeedList), " mph."
```

But it prints:

```
['John Smith', 'Tom Smith']  Was driving at  ['25', '30']  mph.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
>>> SpeedList = ["25","30"]
>>> NameList = ["John Smith","Tom Smith"]
>>> for name, speed in zip(NameList, SpeedList):
...     print (name)," Was driving at ",(speed), " mph."
... 
John Smith  Was driving at  25  mph.
Tom Smith  Was driving at  30  mph.
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name=["John Smith", "Tom Smith"]
speed=["25", "30"]
for i in range(2):
    e=name[i]
    f=speed[i]
    result=e + " was driving at " + f + "mph."
    print result
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While specific code may answer the above question most of the time it is unlikely to help future users finding your answer helpful. Explain why you have come to the specific solution, what you've changed and as much information as possible. Try not only fixing the code but also to help users learn how to get to that solution.